# creating new column after joining two data.tables

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two data.tables, `main` and `metrics`, both keyed by `cid`
I want to add to table `main` the average of each of several values located in metrics.

However, I would like to filter by `code`, only averaging those rows in `metrics` with a given `code`.

```
> metrics
    cid code  DZ value1 value2
1: 1001    A 101      8     21
2: 1001    B 102     11     26
3: 1001    A 103     17     25
4: 1002    A 104     25     39
5: 1002    B 105      6     30
6: 1002    A 106     23     40
7: 1003    A 107     27     32
8: 1003    B 108     16     37
9: 1003    A 109     14     42

# DESIRED OUTPUT
> main
    cid  A.avg.val1   A.avg.val2    B.avg.val1      B.avg.val2    
1: 1001    12.5         23.0            11              26                      
2: 1002    24.0         39.5             6              30            
3: 1003    20.5         37.0            16              37            



#  SAMPLE DATA
set.seed(1)
main <- data.table(cid=1e3+1:3, key="cid")
metrics <- data.table(cid=rep(1e3+1:3, each=3), code=rep(c("A", "B", "A"), 3), DZ=101:109, value1=sample(30, 9), value2=sample(20:50, 9), key="cid")
code.filters <- c("A", "B")
```

These lines get the desired output, but I am having difficulty assigning the new col back into main.  (also, doing it programatically would be preferred).

```
main[metrics[code==code.filters[[1]]]][,  list(mean(c(value1))), by=cid]
main[metrics[code==code.filters[[1]]]][,  list(mean(c(value2))), by=cid]
main[metrics[code==code.filters[[2]]]][,  list(mean(c(value1))), by=cid]
main[metrics[code==code.filters[[1]]]][,  list(mean(c(value2))), by=cid]
```

Additionally, can someone explain why the following line only takes the last value in each group?

```
main[metrics[ code=="A"],  A.avg.val1 := mean(c(value1))]
```

Comment: Actually it's not a good practice to store calculated values in your database.  Those should be done when outputting the data.

Comment: Maybe, 'not a good practice' was the wrong term.  Maybe, 'what's the point' is better? :-)  One main aspect of calculated values is that they change so why would you want to store that data when it can be calculated on the fly and always accurate.  If you store it and go to recall it, it could be out of date and incorrect already.

Comment: @N1tr0, I think you may have misunderstood the question:  I am not storing the value back into my database, I am storing it in a data.table, ie in memory.

Comment: Ah, ok.  That's what I get for being in an area I don't belong. :)  I have more db and scripting experience.  Not programming.  I'll go back and play in my sandbox. lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working off of @Arun's answer, the following gets the desired results:

```
invisible( 
sapply(code.filters, function(cf)
    main[metrics[code==cf, list(avgv1 = mean(value1), avgv2 = mean(value2)), by=cid],
      paste0(cf, c(".avg.val1", ".avg.val2")) :=list(avgv1, avgv2)]
))

> main
    cid A.avg.val1 A.avg.val2 B.avg.val1 B.avg.val2
1: 1001       12.5       23.0         11         26
2: 1002       24.0       39.5          6         30
3: 1003       20.5       37.0         16         37
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `main`. You can get it directly from `metrics` as follows:

```
> tmp.dt <- metrics[, list(A.avg.val1 = mean(value1[code=="A"]), 
                 A.avg.val2 = mean(value2[code=="A"]), 
                 B.avg.val1 = mean(value1[code == "B"]), 
                 B.avg.val2 = mean(value2[code == "B"])), by=cid]

#     cid A.avg.val1 A.avg.val2 B.avg.val1 B.avg.val2
# 1: 1001       12.5       23.0         11         26
# 2: 1002       24.0       39.5          6         30
# 3: 1003       20.5       37.0         16         37
```

If you still want to subset with `main` just do:

```
main <- data.table(cid = c(1001:1002))
> tmp.dt[main]

#     cid A.avg.val1 A.avg.val2 B.avg.val1 B.avg.val2
# 1: 1001       12.5       23.0         11         26
# 2: 1002       24.0       39.5          6         30
```

Comment: main is much larger data table than in the sample above.  I need it to back to main for further computation.  But thank you for the suggestion!! I think I can work it from here!

Comment: Thanks Arun,  I dont think the `tmp.dt` is required, as I can just wrap your suggestion directly in `main[...]`.  Please see below

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in two steps.  First, get your means, then `reshape` the data

```
foo <- main[metrics]
bar <- foo[, list(val1 = mean(value1), 
                  val2 = mean(value2)), 
           by=c('cid', 'code')]

library(reshape2)
bar.melt <- melt(bar, id.var=c('cid', 'code'))
dcast(data=bar.melt,
      cid ~ code + variable)
```

But really, I'd probably leave the data in the "long" format because I find it much easier to work with!

Comment: Thanks @Justin.  I am hoping to do it in a "data.table-esque" fashion as I am hoping to gain the memory efficiency it affords.